# Using WooCommerce for payments only?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a theme with custom functionality and a "special" landing page. I want to use WooCommerce just for the payment and checkout (because woocommerce is compatible with a lot of payment providers), but I do not need the whole shop overhead. I cannot enter each product in the database, so I would like to create the products virtually in WooCommerce and create invoices for them. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Certainly!
Certainly! It is indeed feasible. You can achieve this by utilizing a WordPress plugin available on wordpress.org. Connect the landing page to WooCommerce using the plugin, and it will function seamlessly.
[Custom Post Type Woocommerce Integration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-woo-integration/)